# Validating NoCaptcha ReCaptcha

Tags: javascript, php, validation, recaptcha

I have looked all over the internet and searched through questions here and haven't been able to find a solution to get recaptcha to validate. I am using 3 files for my form, Html file, JS file for validation(bootstrapValidator) and php file for sending mail which is with phpmailer. The form works sending the mail out and clearing the form when sumbitted. I do have the captcha inserted in the form. 
What I'm trying to figure out is how to get recaptcha to work with the form properly. Right now when I hit send and no fields filled in shows errors, not on captcha. Once fields are filled in properly then errors are removed. Hit send and it will send the information to the to address. Just haven't been able to get recaptcha to work with form so when hit send and captcha is not checked then form won't be sent.

This is just one of the ways I have tried validating by putting it on my php form at the top right above  date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC'); with no luck

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])):
     if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])):
        //your site secret key
        $secret = 'your secret key';
        //get verify response data
        $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
        if($responseData->success):
```

Here is HTML file:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" id="contact_form">
```

Set Up An Appointment

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="allFields">* ALL FIELDS REQUIRED *</div>
 </div>

 <div id="mainContent" class="col-sm-12">

  <!-- Full Name -->

    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="fullname" class="col-md-4 control-label">Full Name*</label>
     <div class="col-md-5 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" name="fullname" class="form-control">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div> 

   <!-- Address -->  

    <div class="form-group"> 
     <label for="address" class="col-md-4 control-label">Address</label>
     <div class="col-md-5 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></i></span>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Address" name="address" class="form-control">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

   <!-- City -->

    <div class="form-group"> 
     <label for="city" class="col-md-4 control-label">City</label>
     <div class="col-md-5 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
       <input type="text" placeholder="City" name="city" class="form-control">
      </div>
     </div> 
    </div>

   <!-- State -->

    <div class="form-group"> 
     <label class="col-md-4 control-label">State</label>
     <div class="col-md-5 selectContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
        <select name="state" class="form-control selectpicker" >
         <option value=" " >Please select your state</option>
         <option>Ohio</option>
         <option>Pennsylvania</option>
        </select>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div> 

   <!-- Zip Code -->

    <div class="form-group"> 
     <label for="zipcode" class="col-md-4 control-label">Zip Code</label>
     <div class="col-md-5 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i></span>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Zip Code" name="zipcode" class="form-control">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

   <!-- Phone -->

    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="phone" class="col-md-4 control-label">Phone #</label>
     <div class="col-md-5 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
       <input type="text" placeholder="(330)222-2222" name="phone" class="form-control">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

   <!-- Email -->

    <div class="form-group"> 
     <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-mail</label>
     <div class="col-md-5 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
       <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail Address" name="email" class="form-control">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

   <!-- Appointment Reason -->

    <div class="form-group"> 
     <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Appt Reason</label>
     <div class="col-md-5 selectContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
        <select name="reason" class="form-control selectpicker" >
         <option value=" ">Select Your Appointment Reason</option>
         <option>Roofing</option>
         <option>Siding</option>
         <option>Doors</option>
         <option>Windows</option>
         <option>Decking</option>
         <option>Comfort Rooms</option>
         <option>Kitchen</option>
        </select>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

   <!-- Appointment Date -->

    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Appt. Date</label>
     <div class="col-md-5 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Date you would like Appointment" name="apptDate" class="form-control">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div> 

   <!-- Appointment Time -->

    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Appt. Time</label>
     <div class="col-md-5 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group date" id="timepicker">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Time you would like Appointment" name="apptTime" class="form-control">
      </div>
     </div> 
    </div>

   <!-- Contact Method -->

    <div class="form-group"> 
     <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Contact You</label>
     <div class="col-md-5 selectContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
        <select name="method" class="form-control selectpicker" >
        <option value=" ">Select Your Contact Method</option>
        <option>Email</option>
        <option>Phone</option>
       </select>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div> 

   <!-- Project Description -->

    <div class="form-group"> 
     <label for="comments" class="col-md-4 control-label">Project Description</label>
     <div class="col-md-5 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
       <textarea name="comments" placeholder="Project Description" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div> 


     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Captcha</label>
      <div class="col-md-5 inputGroupContainer">
       <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-5" id="captchaMessage"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Submit Button -->

    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-5">
     <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
     </div>
    </div>



 </div> <!-- mainContent -->

</fieldset>
</form>
```

JS File:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({

    // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {

            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "appt.php",
              data: $('#contact_form').serialize(),
              success: function(){
                $('#contact_form').each(function(){
                      this.reset();
               $(contact_form).data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();
                });
             },
              error: function(){
                alert("error");
              }
            });//close ajax
    },
    fields: {
        fullname: {
            validators: {
                    stringLength: {
                    min: 2,
                },
                    notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please supply your full name'
                }
            }
        },
         address: {
            validators: {
                 stringLength: {
                    min: 8,
                },
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please supply your street address'
                }
            }
        },
        city: {
            validators: {
                 stringLength: {
                    min: 4,
                },
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please supply your city'
                }
            }
        },
        state: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please select your state'
                }
            }
        },
        zipcode: {
            validators: {
                stringLength: {
                    min: 5,
                },
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please supply your zip code'
                },
                zipCode: {
                    country: 'US',
                    message: 'Please supply a vaild zip code'
                }
            }
        },
         phone: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please supply your phone number'
                },
                phone: {
                    country: 'US',
                    message: 'Please supply a vaild phone number with area code'
                }
            }
        },
         email: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please supply your email address'
                },
                emailAddress: {
                    message: 'Please supply a valid email address'
                }
            }
        },
        reason: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please select what your appointment is for'
                }
            }
        },
        method: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please select your preferred contact method'
                }
            }
        },
        comments: {
            validators: {
                  stringLength: {
                    min: 10,
                    max: 200,
                    message:'Please enter at least 10 characters and no more than 200'
                },
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please supply a description of your project'
                }
                }
            },

        }
    })
 });
```

PHP File to send:

```
<?php
/**
 * This example shows settings to use when sending via Google's Gmail servers.
 */

//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');   

//Contact Form Data
$fullnameField = $_POST['fullname'];
$addressField = $_POST['address'];
$cityField = $_POST['city'];
$stateField = $_POST['state'];
$zipcodeField = $_POST['zipcode'];
$phoneField = $_POST['phone'];
$emailField = $_POST['email'];
$apptReasonField = $_POST['reason'];
$apptDateField = $_POST['apptDate'];
$apptTimeField = $_POST['apptTime'];
$methodField = $_POST['method'];
$commentsField = $_POST['comments'];

require 'mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer();

//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.aol.com';
// use
// $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
// if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6

//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;

//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "xxxxxx";

//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "xxxxxxxx";

//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('xxxxxxxx');

//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('xxxxxxxxxx');

//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'Information For Appointment Wanted';

//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->Body = <<<EOD
<br><p>Here is the information $fullnameField entered in your Appointment form.</p>
<br><hr><br>
<b>Name:</b>&nbsp; $fullnameField<hr><br>
<b>Address:</b>&nbsp; $addressField<hr><br>
<b>City:</b>&nbsp; $cityField<hr><br>
<b>State:</b>&nbsp; $stateField<hr><br>
<b>Zip Code:</b>&nbsp; $zipcodeField<hr><br>
<b>Phone #:</b>&nbsp; $phoneField<hr><br>
<b>E-mail:</b>&nbsp; $emailField<hr><br>
<b>Appointment Reason:</b>&nbsp; $apptReasonField<hr><br>
<b>Date Wanted For Appointment:</b>&nbsp; $apptDateField<hr><br>
<b>Time Wanted For Appointment:</b>&nbsp; $apptTimeField<hr><br>
<b>Best Way To Contact You:</b>&nbsp; $methodField<hr><br>
<b>Project Description:</b>&nbsp; $commentsField<hr><br>
EOD;


//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

//send the message, check for errors
if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{
    echo "Message has been sent";
}

?>
```

Comment: For a beginner question, it is not too shabby but it still a little too much to read though to provide a quick answer. Currently I am reviewing, so this is just an FYI.

Comment: @Xorifelse no problem I appreciate it very much so.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially trying to extend your client side validation to include your reCaptcha. Since the reCaptcha isn't an input I don't believe you can extend your Bootstrap validator very easily. You can however add some additional javascript to add this validation.

- You need some javascript variable to keep track of whether your reCaptcha has been solved:

  ```
  var captcha_passed = false;
  ```
- Tell Google's reCaptcha to call your function upon successful completion:

  ```
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="on_captcha_filled" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></div>
  ```
- Add another label to let your users know that this was missed. Make it hidden. The javascript will unhide it if they submit without the reCaptcha.

  ```
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Captcha</label>
      <div class="col-md-5 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="on_captcha_filled" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></div>
      <label id="lblCaptchaRequired" hidden>Please complete the reCaptcha</label>
  </div>
  ```
- Add javascript function to be called by the reCaptcha:

  ```
  /*
  *   Google reCaptcha data-callback handler.
  *   Sets captcha_passed to true to allow form submission and hides captcha required label.
  */
  function on_captcha_filled() {
      captch_passed = true;
      $('#lblCaptchaRequired').hidden = true;
  }
  ```
- Add a check to your submit handler to verify that the reCaptcha has passed:

  ```
  submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {
      if (captcha_passed) {
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "appt.php",
              data: $('#contact_form').serialize(),
              success: function(){
                  $('#contact_form').each(function(){
                      this.reset();
                      $(contact_form).data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();
                  });
              },
              error: function(){
                  alert("error");
              }
          });//close ajax
      }
      else {
          $('#lblCaptchaRequired').hidden = false;
      }
  },
  ```

Now when your user attempts to submit without first completing the reCaptcha they will be notified and the form will not submit.